# Error connecting to SQL database from Rstudio

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

Could anyone advise why the script below gives me an error when I try to connect to the sql database?

I have used the exact same method to connect to other databases on our server without issue

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 08001: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to
> SQL Server [67].   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login
> timeout expired  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid
> connection string attribute  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online.

Code

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                 Server = "MWOS-DBSERVER/BETGENIUSFEEDDB", #had to swop out the backslash
                 Database = "Mindset",
                 UID = "sa",
                 PWD = "***********", #I have used the correct password
                 Port = 1433)
```

Comment: It's likely your code is fine, you just can't connect due to a network issue. Try testing connection from ODBC

Comment: In the error _Named Pipes Provider_ and _A network-related or instance-specific error_ are usually giveaways to network. Your password is fine, otherwise you would've got an authentication error

Comment: BTW the normal syntax is `MWOS-DBSERVER\BETGENIUSFEEDDB` not `MWOS-DBSERVER/BETGENIUSFEEDDB`. Maybe you need `MWOS-DBSERVER\\BETGENIUSFEEDDB`

Comment: Try using an instance name in the `Server` parameter, or use a `Port` parameter, but not both. Prefer to use the `Port` parameter if you know it which then avoids a dependency on the SQL Browser Service.

Comment: Thanks Nick.McDermaid that was the issue. Also thanks to the other guys for your suggestions